# Ошибка при запуске .jar файла, со сторонними библиотеками, как исправить?

Tags: java, maven

Создал проект с maven, добавил сторонние библиотеки в maven, забилдил их в .jar и при обращении к ним пишет такую ошибку:"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser", когда обращается к сторонним библиотекам в maven
Как это исправить??

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>Crypto-currency</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    curren.start.Main
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-ui_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Выложите код pom. Вообще NoClassDef часто происходит из-за ошибки в инициазации класса, если мне память не изменяет, что-то такое было у меня когда-то, вроде как не обязательно с либами связано. А возможно просто не упакованы либы в jar и нужно подключить что-то вроде shaded-plugin.

Comment: @Uraty Изменил, смотрите

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208321/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-json-simple-jsonobject-running-outside-of-ne

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn

Comment: А вы случаем запускаете не просто jar? Потому что насколько я понимаю, нормально будет работать только тот, что ***-with-dependencies.jar. А вообще еще не совсем понятно, что вы имеет ввиду под "забилдил их в .jar"ю Вы весь проект с либами в jar билдите или отдельно либы, а потом куда то их подключаете?

Comment: Весь проект. Ну в artifacts добавил все библиотеки, но результат всё равно тот же

Comment: Artifacts? Это случайно не пунктик из менюшки в IDEA? Если да, то он никакого отношения к билду maven не имеет. Вы должны вызвать mvn clean install, после чего в папке target у вас появися jar-with-dependencies, его и нужно пытаться запускать. Хотя может быть и не прокатит, по карайней мере я в свое время намучался с ним в итоге перешел на shaded-plugin вместо assembly-plugin.

Comment: @Uraty Всё понял, где я ошибся. Его надо вызвать через консоль mvn clean install?

Comment: Да, можно через консоль, а можно через IDEA там есть панелька maven